# mysql calculate percentage between two sub queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to work out the percentage of a number of students who meet certain criteria.
I have 3 separate tables that I need to get data from, and then I need to get the total from one table (student) as the total of students. 
Then I need to use this total, to divide the COUNT of the no of students in the 2nd query.

So basically I am trying to get a count of ALL the students that are in the DB first.
Then count the no of students that appear in my main query (the one returning the data).
Then I need to perform the calculation that will take the noOfStudents (2) and divide by the main total (24) (no of students in DB) then *100 to give me the percentage of students who have met the criteria in the main query.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, s.RegistrationDate, s.Email, d.ReviewDate,(r.description) AS "Viva"  , COUNT(*) AS "No of Students"
FROM student s
INNER JOIN dates d 
ON s.id=d.student_identifier 
INNER JOIN reviews r
ON d.review_Identifier=r.id 
WHERE r.description = "Viva Date"
GROUP BY s.student_identifier
ORDER BY s.student_identifier)
) AS Completed
WHERE Completed.ReviewDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'
;
```

I need to output the fields following the second SELECT and this data in turn will be displayed via PHP/HTML code on a page (the BETWEEN dates will be sent via '%s').

I wondered if I should be using 2 separate queries and then getting the value (24) from the first query to perform the calculation in the second query, but I have not been able to work out how to save as 2 separate queries and then reference the first query.

I am also not sure if it is possible to display an overall % total at the same time as outputting the individual rows that meet the criteria?

I am trying to teach myself SQL, so I apologise if I have made any glaring mistakes/assumptions in any of the above, and would appreciate any advice that's out there.

Thank you.

Comment: You've got to stop using [pre ansi 92 join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalPopulation, 
COUNT(d.student_identifier='student') as TotalStudents, 
COUNT(d.student_identifier='student')/ count(*) *100 as Percentage of students  
from students s 
inner join dates d
on s.id = d.student_identifier
inner join reviews r
on r.id = d.review_Identifier
WHERE d.ReviewDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-12-01' and r.description = 'Viva Date';
```

You do not need first name last name if you are just looking for counts, necessarily.
This get's the count(*) of table, then whatever flag you use to identify a student in the second count(), you just had it grouped by before, which could give you wrong results considering there's much else in your select before aggregation.

You could also try:

```
SELECT d.student_identifier, s.firstname, s.lastname, 
s.RegistrationDate, s.Email, d.ReviewDate,(r.description) AS "Viva" 
FROM student s
INNER JOIN dates d 
ON s.id=d.student_identifier 
INNER JOIN reviews r
ON d.review_Identifier=r.id 
WHERE r.description = "Viva Date" and d.ReviewDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'
ORDER BY s.student_identifier
```

Now, if you want to return a list, that's the second one, if you want to return a count, you would use the first query and adjust to your student_identifier.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the fields to be output in my results because I need to show the list of students.  This was my point as to whether what I am trying to do is actually possible - i.e. display all relevant students whose Viva Date is between the to date inputs, AS WELL as then calculating the percentage from the total students.

Comment: I have tried your code above, but that just gives me one row with 

Total Population      TotalStudents     Percentage of Students
2                     2                 100.0000

Comment: You probably cannot do this. What will happen if you don't group by everything before the count aggregation will give you a list of results but they won't be correct. If you want to do that you should do: firstname, lastname, e-mail, student_identifier, registration date, review date as a table or temp table and then aggregate that later. You don't want to do both because results will vary too much.

Comment: Only other alternative would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on the first query like GROUP_CONCAT(concat(firstname,',', lastname),'-') and this will return all the names associated to that count.

Comment: Thanks @Hituptony.  I have used the GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT in other queries I have written, but because I am bringing the recordset back into PHP to output on a page, I wasn't sure if I would then be able to get each element from the returned array.

Is it considered bad practice to perhaps do the 2 separate queries, returning the 2 integer values, and then performing the % calculation on the PHP side?

Comment: I think you would be better off to perform the calculation on the SQL side. Also if you're pulling it into PHP you could just put them in two separate tables, like a report. Have the first count going across the top, and then have the "breakdown" of the students below...might be a nice touch!

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice, but I know that it's easier to just do the calculation in SQL as that's low level so any errors you might get arise in the data, and now in the high-level application language

Comment: Thanks again @Hituptony.  I would love to get it working on the SQL side, but I have been unable to work it out.  I have it working on the PHP side now, by just getting the total number of students in one query and then I perform the calculation (after getting the results of the second query).

I'm afraid I don't know how to put into two separate tables apart from what I am doing in running the two queries, and now I just output the % total as an additional echo statement underneath the results.